# Indefinite integral $\int \frac {\mathrm d x} {p^2 + q^2 \cosh^2 a x}$

Tags: indefinite-integrals

Spiegel's "Mathematical Handbook of Formulas and Tables" (Schaum, 1968), item $14.584$ gives:

$$\int \dfrac {\mathrm d x} {p^2 + q^2 \cosh^2 a x} = \begin{cases} \dfrac 1 {2 a p \sqrt {p^2 + q^2} } \ln \left({\dfrac {p \tanh a x + \sqrt {p^2 + q^2} } {p \tanh a x - \sqrt {p^2 + q^2} } }\right) + C \\ \dfrac 1 {a p \sqrt {p^2 + q^2} } \arctan \left({\dfrac {p \tanh a x} {\sqrt {p^2 + q^2} } }\right) + C \end{cases}$$

(As usual he glosses over negative argument to the $\ln$, but all you need to do is modulus it.)

He does **not** give the conditions under which either case holds. This is crucial.

First I multiplied top and bottom by $\operatorname {csch}^2 a x$, then used $\operatorname {csch}^2 a x = \coth^2 a x - 1$ for the bottom, then substituted $u = \coth a x$ to convert it into the form:

$$\frac 1 {a (p^2 + q^2) } \int \frac {\mathrm d u} {\frac {p^2} {p^2 + q^2} - u^2}$$

I can't see there is **any other case** than that $\dfrac {p^2} {p^2 + q^2}$ is positive, hence:

$$\frac 1 {a (p^2 + q^2) } \int \frac {\mathrm d u} {\left({\frac p {\sqrt {p^2 + q^2} } }\right)^2 - u^2}$$

This is a standard integral, giving:

$$\frac 1 {2 a p \sqrt {p^2 + q^2} } \ln \left|{\frac {\sqrt {p^2 + q^2} u - p} {\sqrt {p^2 + q^2} u + p} }\right| + C$$

which leads to:

$$\dfrac 1 {2 a p \sqrt {p^2 + q^2} } \ln \left({\dfrac {p \tanh a x + \sqrt {p^2 + q^2} } {p \tanh a x - \sqrt {p^2 + q^2} } }\right) + C$$

And that all works fine, no worries.

BUT, as far as I can see, there is no way to get to the arctangent result. To get there, we need $u^2 + k^2$ for some constant $k$, and I can't see how to get there from the given integrand.

Comment: Are you sure it shouldn't be $\text{artanh } $ in stead of $\arctan$?

Comment: @A-LevelStudent Good question, but I'm absolutely quite sure. If that were the case then the question would be solved as the arctanh construction is equivalent to the log of that quotient, as far as I remember without looking up which one goes on top and which one on the bottom. Besides, if that were the case, it would not be presented as a "cases" construct, but as an alternative with an "equals" separating the two results. (It actually says $\tan^{-1}$ but I dislike that.

Comment: That's why I thought it may be $\text{artanh}$ as then it fits very nicely, but you have a point about there being 2 options. I am differentiating the $\arctan$ one now and seeing if it does work.

Comment: There is a version of the sneaky Weierstrass substitution that applies to hyperbolic functions,

Comment: @WillJagy but isn't that still in terms of $\tanh$ and not $\tan$?

Comment: @A-LevelStudent neither one by nature. All it does is make a rational function, namely a polynomial divided by a polynomial. Then partial fractions, which is not entirely predictable

Comment: @WillJagy thanks, I meant a substitution involving $\tanh$ as opposed to $\tan$. Good luck in solving it with that, I look forward to your results.

Comment: @WillJagy Yes, I haven't tried that approach - although I'm aware of it, I usually find it's quicker when in hyperbolics to make the substitution $u = e^{ax}$ as this usually gets me where I want to go quicker than when i use the full $\tanh (ax/2)$ subst. I'll give it a go tomorrow perhaps when I'm fresh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note
$$ \frac12\ln {\dfrac {p \tanh a x + \sqrt {p^2 + q^2} } {p \tanh a x - \sqrt {p^2 + q^2} } }
= \frac12\ln {\frac {\frac {p \tanh a x }{\sqrt {p^2 + q^2} }  + 1}{\frac{p \tanh a x }{\sqrt {p^2 + q^2} }-1}} 
=\tanh^{-1}\frac {p \tanh a x }{\sqrt {p^2 + q^2} }\\
$$

So, there is a typo in the second expression.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I needed confirmation of. Spiegel does have a few errors. This is just another one.

Answer (score 1):

The second result is wrong it would seem, at least if it's supposed to hold for all values of $p, q,a$. Letting $p=q=a=1$ and using my calculator to evaluate the integral between $0$ and $1$:

$$\int_0^1\frac{1}{1+\cosh^2 x}dx=0.4257352463...$$
But $$\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\arctan\frac{\tanh 1}{\sqrt2}-\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\arctan\frac{\tanh 0}{\sqrt2}=0.3493059377...$$